# How to echo out the contents of every text file that in a directory?

Tags: php, filesystems

I have created a directory with some files in there:

- index.php
- one.txt
- two.txt
- three.txt
- four.txt

In the `index.php` page, I am currently using this code to echo out all of the files within the directory:

```
<?php
$blacklist = array("index.php");

if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." &&  !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) {
            echo "$entry\n";
        }

    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Now, if anyone views the `index.php` page, this is what they'll see:

```
one.txt two.txt three.txt four.txt
```

As you can see from the PHP code, `index.php` is blacklisted so it is not echoed out.

However, I would like to go a step further than this and echo out the contents of each text file rather than the filenames. With the new PHP code (that I need help with creating), whenever someone visits the `index.php` page, this is what they'll now see:

(Please ignore what is in the asterisks, they are not a part of the code, they just indicate what each text file contains)

```
Hello  ** this is what the file **one.txt** contains **

ok  ** this is what the file **two.txt** contains **

goodbye  ** this is what the file **three.txt** contains **

text  ** this is what the file **four.txt** contains **
```

Overall:

I would like to echo out the contents of every file in the directory (they are all text files) aside from `index.php`.

Comment: In response to the first version of the question, I tend to advise against making requests about how your question should be received, and how people should (not) vote, since doing so can result in the downvotes you are wanting to avoid. As it stands the question is quite clear and I don't expect it to be downvoted. However, it could do with an explanation of what you are stuck on - it seems you asking how to read a file into a variable, which could probably be found using a search engine.

Comment: See here: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+read+file+contents - first result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to put the file into a string.

```
<?php
   $blacklist = array("index.php");

   if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

          if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." &&  !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) {
              echo "$entry " . file_get_contents($entry) . "\n";
          }

       }

      closedir($handle);
   }
?>
```

Furthermore, you could use PHP's [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function to filter only the `.txt` files out, that way you do not have to blacklist files if you're going to be adding more files to that directory that need ignored.

Here is how it would be done using the `glob` function.

```
<?php
   foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
      echo "$filename " . file_get_contents($filename) . "\n";
   }
?>
```

Comment: This only seems to be echoing out the contents of one file out of the four

Comment: @Osman Take a look into the source code to make sure, that the code is really only printing one file. I don't see why this code should fail

Comment: @Osman: I don't mean to be excessively critical, but you _might_ be downvoted for not doing any debugging. Now you have some code to play with, can you echo out the variables on your dev machine, and see where the problem might be?

Comment: @Osman - while I agree the code shouldn't fail, I also added the solution if you wanted to use the glob function to clean the code up a little bit and make it a little more maintainable.

Comment: It should be noted that `glob("*.txt")` will also match directories with that name, not just files.  These problems have been encountered before and solved. This is one answer to your question: `How is this answer more useful than any of the solutions already provided? ` phpBB and Laravel use Finder for a reason.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher The solution I posted would work fine for their requirements. I'm not going to argue semantics of why you should use a framework or not. Just don't argue that it's reinventing the wheel when you're throwing in the overhead of a full library for a simple operation that requires minimal native code.

Answer (score 1):

This would print the contents of the files. You can do some workaround if the path is not the current path and writing some kind of boundary between the files contents.

```
<?php
$blacklist = array("index.php");

if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." &&  !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) {
            echo  file_get_contents($entry) . "\n";
        }

    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This only seems to be echoing out the contents of one file out of the four

Comment: If you are looping over all the files in the directory as `$entry`, every time you loop over that `while` statement, the `$entry` var should contain a different filename, so it should print the content of all files in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Never reinvent the wheel. Use composer.

Require [symfony/finder](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/finder)

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

class Foo
{
    public function getTextFileContents($dir)
    {
        $finder = (new Finder())->files()->name('*.txt');
        foreach ($finder->in($dir) as $file) {
            $contents = $file->getContents();
            // do something while file contents...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this answer more useful than any of the solutions already provided? Also, this can be seen as reinventing the wheel more than using the built in PHP functions.

Comment: Symfony's finder component is well written and good library to accomplish filesystem related tasks and it uses SPL Iterators [internally](https://github.com/symfony/Finder/blob/master/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php). I also wrote an answer below which doesn't depends any 3rd party library.

Comment: @Brock: different approaches to solving a problem are welcome here - up to a point, more the merrier? `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

I would give a chance to some [SPL filesystem iterators](https://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) to accomplish such this task:

```
$dir = '/home/mydirectory';
$rdi = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$rdi = new \RegexIterator($rdi, '/\.txt$/i');
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi, \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    echo 'Contents of the '.$file->getPathname().' is: ';
    echo file_get_contents($file->getPathname());
}
```

This will recursively find & iterate all `.txt` files in given directory, including sub-directories.

Since each `$file` in iteration is a `FilesystemIterator` instance, you can use [all related methods](https://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php) for additional controls like `$file->isLink()` (true for symbolic links), `$file->isReadable()` (false for unreadable files) etc..

If you don't want lookup sub-folders, just change the **RecursiveDirectoryIterator** in the second line from:

```
$rdi = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
```

to:

```
$rdi = new \DirectoryIterator($dir, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @brock-b said, you could use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get the full list of files and [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to grab the contents:

```
$blacklist = array('index.php');

$files = glob('*.txt'); # could be *.* if needed
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (!in_array(basename($file), $blacklist)) {
        echo file_get_contents($file);
    }
}
```

*Note: the blacklist wont be hit since you're seeking for `*.txt` files. Only useful when doing an `*.*` or `*.php` file search*